# Charge 1.9.8 Error After Install?

Tags: charge

I just installed the latest version of Charge on my 2.10.1 ExpressionEngine site and now I'm seeing the following error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')' in /wwwroot/system/expressionengine/third_party/charge/mcp.charge.php on line 800

Anyone else having this issue?

Answer (score 1):

This was corrected in the 1.9.9 release.  Problem solved.